# Error: querySrv ESERVFAIL _mongodb._tcp.*********.*****.mongodb.net

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I’ve made an mern website using MongoDB however I keep getting this error from time to time, if I entirely reset the application it works for a day then I get this error

```
**Error: querySrv ESERVFAIL \_mongodb.\_tcp.\*\*\*\*\*\*.\*\*\*\*\*.[mongodb.net](http://mongodb.net/)**
```

however, I don’t get this error on localhost I only get this error on Hostinger(VPS) hosting. Please help I’m struggling with this for 2-3 weeks.

Thank you.

NODEJS REACT MONGODB

I have changed the wifi DNS to google DNS and also tried changing the DNS resolver on Hostinger to google DNS.

I don't understand the issue as it works totally fine for 1 day then the next day when I try to access the website I get

```
root@shahikohinoor:\~/bigbasketuae# npm run server

\\\> bigbasket@1.0.0 server

\\\> nodemon backend/server

\[nodemon\] 2.0.22

\[nodemon\] to restart at any time, enter \`rs\`

\[nodemon\] watching path(s): \*.\*

\[nodemon\] watching extensions: js,mjs,json

\[nodemon\] starting \`node backend/server.js\`

**Server running in production mode on port 8800 (HTTPS)**

**Error: querySrv ESERVFAIL \_mongodb.\_tcp.bigaser.00t4.mongodb.net**

\[nodemon\] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```